# does matter exist?

Tags: matter

i suddenly think this out of nowhere. suppose when we see for example cells at the micro scale, we will see solid objects and space, and when we see these solid objects at the atomic scale, we will see more solid objects(which is atom) and space, now we can see the pattern, what if in the future we can see smaller than an atom and when we look more closely the atom, we will be able to see more solid objects and space again. and as we continue to do that, does solid matter really exist, or is it just an illusion of information arriving from (I actually don't know how to call it) spacetime density that somehow maintains its density. Because, we can see something if some information arrive to us, what if that information also a spacetime density itself

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Unfortunately, this is more a philosophical than a physics question.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, we can "see" objects much smaller than an atom using very, very powerful microscopes called *particle accelerators*. With these, we can tell what's inside not just an atom, not just its nucleus, but inside the protons and neutrons that make up the nucleus itself. What we see is that protons and neutrons are mostly empty space with three point-like particles called *quarks* running around inside each one of them.

It is not known whether quarks themselves possess any sort of internal structure, but there's presently no evidence in hand to suggest this.

In our everyday experience, when we feel the "solidity" of a massive object, we are actually experiencing the electrostatic repulsion between the electron clouds surrounding the atoms from which our skin is made and the similar clouds surrounding the atoms of the  object being felt. And the reason that such an object is unyielding to our hands is that its atoms are held together by bonds that involve the sharing of electrons between adjacent atoms.

The study of those bonds is the basis of the field of *chemistry*. The study of the forces that hold nuclei together is the province of *particle physics*.